# Possible values of the GCD of two polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial in $\mathbb Q[X]$. Find the possible values
>   of $d=gcd(p(x),p(x)+x-1)$.

I have:  $gcd(p(x),p(x)+x-1)=gcd(p(x),x-1)$

Is the answer to the question: $d(x) \in \{1,x-1\}$?

Comment: If $d$ must be monic, yes.

Comment: Great, thank you. If you write that as answer, set it as the answer to the question.